# How to do a svn compare between local code base and latest from repository like in Eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse, when click `Synchronize` view it will show up a tree structure of diff comparison from local to svn repo. Click on each file will pop up view to show code diff.

[image]

Is there a similar feature in Intellij and how to activate it? I am on latest Intellij Ultimate btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Version Control button on the bottom, click on the Incoming tab. Hit the refresh button (circle with arrows). First time it will ask you if you want to set up automatic refresh. It will then show any changes pending from the repository. You can click on files and get a diff. (You may have to right click on a revision and select "Show Affected Files".)

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact same view in IDEA. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119596

You can use Subversion -> Compare to the Latest repository version from a file's context menu.

There is also the Incoming tab that shows changes from the server not yet applied to your working copy. You could invoke Show Diff with local from the Details pane of the Incoming change

Comment: thanks. But wow I think this should be a nice / user-friendly feature but seems not recognized by IntelliJ. The item 3) brought up in the ticket does have a valid reason to support by modern IDE. Good practice or not, it is under user's discretion. It's a vivid example of engineer geek tried to decide business requirement, but finally hurt subscriptions from people like me. Maybe IntelliJ is so popular so doesn't care :).